# jquery dropdown slidedown doesnt work

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I am trying to `slideDown()` a hidden div but it only `show()` it without the `slideDown()` effect

http://jsfiddle.net/BQYQ5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Min-height breaks animation. Read this
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4623

And solution
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Around_The_Minimum_Height_Glitch

Comment: i have added height just for testing purposes.. now i see when the div gets data it will be fine... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $("#dropdown").slideDown("slow");
});

$("#dropdown").hide();

<a href="#">[open]</a>
<div id="dropdown">
    data go here
</div>
```